# Swift: Open all external links within a webview in Safari, NOT in webview

Tags: ios, swift, safari, uiwebview, wkwebview

I wrote a simple app which calls a webview (located at XXXXXX.com/webview.php

This is my code which opens my webview in swift:

```
if let url = URL(string: "https://www.XXXXXX.com/webview.php") {
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Now, all **internal links** which are within this webview-system (e.g. /webview_subsite2.php) are opening within this webview. Thats wonderful.
BUT I want that all **external links (target=_blank)** open in Safari-Browser.
How can I achieve this?

My previous question was marked as duplicate, but it isnt.
The point is, that the above posted code is NOT the call of a link!
It is the call of the webview.
My question concerns how to open all external links **INSIDE this webview**, which is located at XXXXXX.com/webview.php (domain censored) in Safari and NOT within this webview-Frame. And a solution in swift is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

use [shouldStartLoadWithRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebviewdelegate/1617945-webview?language=objc) webView delegate method and check `navigationType.linkClicked` type and open the link in safari

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(request.url!, options: [:])
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        }
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Lets say: The Sourcecode of the webview xxxxx.com/webview.php is: <a href=http://google.de target=_blank>google</a> and i wanna open this Link to Google in Safari.

Comment: where do you copy this function?

Comment: Add this method where you set your webview delegate

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:decisionHandler:` on your WKNavigationDelegate. Return `WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow` to the completion handler for URLs that match your "internal" domain, and `WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel` for ones that don't, and also handle those URLs to load in Safari.